# Problemas con Report Viewer en aplicación WinForms y Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, windows10

Buenas trades compañeros. Tengo la siguente forma de pantalla:
[image: Forma reporte con Report Viewer]

y el si pulso cualquiera de los radio buttons este es el código (cambiando el nombre del campo en ORDER BY):

```
if (rbOrdName.Checked)
   {
       RV.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
       RV.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\\Files\\rptVehicle.rdlc";
       cn = ObjShow.BDConn();
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       SqlDataAdapter da;
       Txt = "SELECT * FROM tblMake ORDER BY Ex_Make_Name";
       da = new SqlDataAdapter(Txt, cn);
       da.Fill(ds);
       ReportDataSource data = new ReportDataSource("Vehicle", ds.Tables[0]);
       RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(data);
       ObjShow.BDClose();
       RV.RefreshReport();
   }
```

El mismo se ejecuta perfectamente pero al hacer el refresh obtengo:
[image: Misma pantalla en ejecución]

Açun cuando he investigado en internet aparentemente como que soy el único que tiene este problema y en algunos casos las repuestas que dan para casos parecidos desde mi punto de vista no es satisfactorio, ya que indican editar el XLM y eliminar la parte de parámetros, etc.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda o información. Gracias anticipadas

Comment: intentaste llevar el codigo a una ruta mas corta ? que no sea `c:\Users\...` porque a veces el largo de estas rutas afecta. Lleva el .sln a una ruta corta como ser `c:\Trabajos` y alli pones toda la estructura

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo Leandro, por la limitación de 256 caracteres, pero yo no puedo controlar donde lo instala el cliente. De allí mi problema, pero probarñe tu idea, Seguiré diciendo que Microsoft le amarga la vida a los programadores. Gracias

Comment: Leandro tu recomendación me hizo dudar, y la probé, pero el error continua igual. Se te ocurre alguna otra cosa que no sea preguntar a Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace poco tenía un problema similar con el viewer, desinstalé la versión anterior e instalé este [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/) y funcionó correctamente, por favor intenta y nos confirma el resultado.

`Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -Version 150.1449.0`

Comment: Gracias, pero esto lo solucioné hace tiempo y es como dices.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que noto por el mensaje es que puede que la version del rdlc sea mas actual que la soportada por el ReportViewer.

Como se menciona en el titulo "Adding the Report Viewer control to a new Windows Forms project"

[Integrating Reporting Services Using the Report Viewer Controls - Get Started](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2016)

Podrias ver de actualizar la version del `viewer` a una mas reciente usando `nuget`, es por eso que usa

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms
```

aunque podrias hacerlo tambien de forma visual usando el manger de nuget

A donde apunto es que no uses el control de ReportViewer que se incluye en el Visual Studio, usa una version actualizada desde nuget

Comment: Leandro todo eso ya lo hice. Adicionalmente eliminé Report Viewer del toolbar, lo eliminé de la referencias  y borre la carpeta 'Packages'. Salí de VS, al entrar lo reinstalé y cuando traté de usarlo me dice que ya está instalado.Como tu eres más experimentado que yo en VS, podrías ponerte en contacto conmigo por maximiliano.gil@gmail.com e intercambiaríamos ideas y no me importaría negociar contigo si es posible. Por cierto estoy usando VS 2017 que no trae Visual Studio instalado. En VS 2015 no tuve problemas y tampoco lo trae.

Comment: que version de Sql Server tienes instalada,en realidad como creas el .rdlc? porque lo que indica es un tema de versiones con la cual creas el rdlc que no esta soportada por el viewer, intenta crear el reporte desde el mismo VS, el problema viene por este lado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139815/change-rdl-version-for-rdlc-reports-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Leandro la versión que tengo es SQL Server Management Studio 18 y los reportes los creo directamente en Visual Studio. Chequeo el link que me envias.

Comment: Adicionalmente, Leandro, hay alguna manera de desinstalar totalmente (Control del toolbok, referencias y del NET) ya que con todo lo que he hecho ahora tengo un error cuando solo quiero que presente el Reporte (sin colocar ningún filtro) y el error es: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.'

Comment: validaste que el proyecto tenga la referencia a `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` ? valida que esa libreria este en el \bin\Debug cuando se compila el .exe, sino esta entonces falta la dll por eso no la encuentra. No es un tema de desintalar, sino de agregar la referencia a la libreria faltante, valida ademas que sea la version correcta, porque puede que tengas la referencia pero de otra version

Comment: Leandro, la referencia a la librería Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common existe, y en el directorio debug no, Pero me di cuenta de que otros reportes funcionaban y uno en específico no, suporgo que de tantos cambios que he hecho perdió el dataset, ya que reconstrui todo y ahora funciona. La versión de RDLC que tengo es 15.3.1 y el Report Viewer es la última versión en Nuget. Seguiré investigando por qué los filtros y los parámetrtos no me funcionan y si tienes otras ideas serán bienvenidas. Gracias y espero tus recomendaciones y ayudas.